# How to insert a big sentence with commas into MySQL with python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

how to insert a whole sentence like (ex:  text, plus comma,...) into one column?

here's my code :

```
cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO company(company_name, company_information, company_location, company_phone_number, comp_web_site,photo) VALUES ('{}','{}', '{}', '{}', '{}',{})".format(
                company_name, company_information, company_location, phone_number, web_site,image, 'NOW()'))
```

here's when i run the code

MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Etudes Techniques Bâtiment, G.e.t.b. Ingénierie','\nGETB Engineering est un ...' at line 1")

Comment: what happens when you run your code?

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Etudes Techniques Bâtiment, G.e.t.b. Ingénierie','\nGETB Engineering est un ...' at line 1")

Comment: You have one or more single quotes in your string.  Instead of using string formatting, use parameter substitution as shown in the linked duplicate so that values are properly escaped.

Comment: i fixed it, used "{}" instead of '{}', thanks for replying